# PowerQuery List.Generate: Order of Argument Evaluation?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Regarding PowerQuery's [List.Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) function.

Could someone please help me understand why the first version of this List.Generate call returns **2** elements (desired result), while the second returns only **1** element (only the initial value - an empty list)? The only difference in the two calls is found on line 3.

### Working query

```
Source = 
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[Page = 1, NextPage = "next", Response = [next = "next", results = {}]],
            each [Page] <= MaxPages and NextPage <> null,
            each[
                Page = [Page] + 1,
                Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://platform.myapi.com/public_api?",
                                                        [
                                                           Query=
                                                            [
                                                                page=Text.From([Page]),
                                                                page_size=Text.From(1000)
                                                            ],
                                                           Headers=[#"x-api-key"=#"ApiKey"],
                                                           RelativePath=relativePath
                                                        ]
                                                       )
                                          ),
                NextPage = [Response][next]
            ],
            each [Response][results]
        ), ...
```

[image: good result set2]
*Correct. 2 lists - the initial, empty list, and the results of the API call*

### Query I think should work, but doesn't

```
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[Page = 1, NextPage = "next", Response = [next = "next", results = {}]],
            each [Page] <= MaxPages and [Response][next] <> null, // only change
            each[
                Page = [Page] + 1,
                Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://platform.myapi.com/public_api?",
                                                        [
                                                           Query=
                                                            [
                                                                page=Text.From([Page]),
                                                                page_size=Text.From(1000)
                                                            ],
                                                           Headers=[#"x-api-key"=#"ApiKey"],
                                                           RelativePath=relativePath
                                                        ]
                                                       )
                                          ),
                NextPage = [Response][next]
            ],
            each [Response][results]
        ),...
```

[image: incorrect results]

*Incorrect. Only the initial empty list*

For clarity, here is sample output from the API. It’s a paginated API with 1,000 records per page. So, since there are only 697 records returned, there is no further page to pull, and the `next` element is returned as null. There are 697 elements in the `results` array.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In you data, as you state, Response[next] is null (since you only have 687 items).

So the condition:

```
each [Page] <= MaxPages and [Response][next] <> null,
```

Is never met on line 3 of query 2 and no further processing happens.

In the first query, NextPage = "next", so this works.